# Dimension check of automatic objects in explicit interfaces

Tags: fortran, fortran90, subroutine

I always assumed that giving values in automatic sized dummy arguments within subroutine definitions has some benefit in error detection, when the routine is defined inside a module that gives an explicit interface. But following example shows that there is not really a checking of array bounds:

```
module test_mod

   Implicit none

   contains

   !> Testing routine that has an automatic array arr of length n. The integer n is also given.
   !> It is included in a module and has an explicit interface.
   subroutine print_array(n, arr)
      Integer, intent(in) :: n                  !< Size of arr
      Integer, Dimension(n), intent(in) :: arr  !< A test array that should be of size n

      Integer :: i

      do i = 1, n
         print *, 'number:', i, arr(i)
      enddo
   End Subroutine print_array

end module test_mod

program playground

   use test_mod, only : print_array

   ! Call print_array with an array smaller than 3 elements
   Call print_array(3, [8, 9])

end program playground
```

`arr` is created with the dimension of `n` in subroutine `print_array`, but it is not checked if the dimension of the given array is correct. In my example the output is:

```
number:           1           8
number:           2           9
number:           3  -858993460
```

So the 3rd value is taken outside of `arr` bounds and in my case -858993460 is printed. I understand that such behaviour can not generally be catched at compile time. But even using `ifort` with `/check:bounds` option doesn't give an error message at run time.

Therefore, I would like to ask if it is good practice to specify `arr` with `Dimension(n)` or is it even better to define it with `Dimension(:)`. What is the advantage of giving the dimension in such way?

Comment: Possibly [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47913804/3157076) may help you.

Comment: Generally I don't see the point of passing an array and its size as separate arguments, not since Fortran 90 became widely implemented 20+ years ago.  On the rare occasion I write code which depends on knowing the size of an array I figure it out inside the routine.  I don't know if this is widely regarded as good practice or not, but it works for me.  I don't see much use anymore for `dimension(n)` in routine argument declarations.