# Passing arrays to subroutines in Fortran: Assumed shape vs explicit shape

Tags: arrays, fortran, pass-by-reference, subroutine

When passing arrays to procedures, what is best in terms of (1) speed and (2) memory, assumed-shape or explicit shape? A similar question was asked some time ago in this forum but not in these terms:
[Passing size as argument VS assuming shape in Fortran procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913804/passing-size-as-argument-vs-assuming-shape-in-fortran-procedures)

I provide a simple program to show what I mean

```
! Compile with
! ifort /O3 main.f90 -o run_win.exe

module mymod
    USE iso_Fortran_env, ONLY: dp => real64
    implicit none
    private
    public :: dp, sub_trace, sub_trace_es
    
    contains
    
    subroutine sub_trace(mat,trace)
    ! Assumed shape
        implicit none
        real(dp), intent(in) :: mat(:,:)
        real(dp), intent(out) :: trace
        real(dp) :: V(size(mat,dim=1))
        integer :: i,N
        
        if (size(mat,dim=1) /= size(mat,dim=2)) then
            error stop "Input matrix is not square!"
        endif
        
        N = size(mat,dim=1)
        do i=1,N
            V(i) = mat(i,i)
        enddo
        trace = sum(V)
    
    end subroutine sub_trace
    
    subroutine sub_trace_es(n,mat,trace)
    ! Passing array explicit shape
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real(dp), intent(in) :: mat(n,n)
        real(dp), intent(out) :: trace
        real(dp) :: V(n)
        integer :: i
        
        do i=1,n
            V(i) = mat(i,i)
        enddo
        trace = sum(V)
    
    end subroutine sub_trace_es
    
end module mymod    
    
program main
    use mymod, only: dp, sub_trace,sub_trace_es
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: nn=2
    real(dp) :: mat(nn,nn)
    real(dp), allocatable :: mat4(:,:)
    real(dp) :: trace1,trace2,trace3,trace4
    
    write(*,*) "Passing arrays to subroutines:"
    write(*,*) "Assumed-shape vs explicit shape"
    
    mat(1,:) = [2_dp,3_dp]
    mat(2,:) = [4_dp,5_dp]
    
    call sub_trace(mat,trace1)
    
    write(*,*) "trace1 = ", trace1
    
    call sub_trace_es(nn,mat,trace2)
    
    write(*,*) "trace2 = ", trace2
    
    ! First example offered by francescalus:
    call sub_trace_es(2,real([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],dp), trace3)
    
    write(*,*) "trace3 = ", trace3
    
    ! Second example
    mat4 = reshape(real([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],dp),[3,3])
    call sub_trace(mat4, trace4)
    
    write(*,*) "trace4 = ", trace4
        
    pause

end program
```

Comment: An assumed-shape and an explicit-shape array are totally different things (as dummy arguments go), so reducing to even "speed" and "memory" probably doesn't suffice. Can you explain more around what you understand and care about?

Comment: In modern fortran there are two main ways of passing arrays to subroutines and functions: assumed shape dummy arrays (which I illustrate in sub_trace) and explicit shape dummy arrays (which I illustrate in sub_trace_es). The question is (1) which method is best if one wants to maximize the execution speed of the code? (2) which method is best if one wants to minimize the memory footprint of the code, i.e. avoid copying arrays back and forth?

Comment: There are many subtleties. What is faster in one situation will be slower in another. And you can have temporary copies even with assumed shape, when `contiguous` is used carelessly. It may be impossible to say what is faster in general. Copying is slow, but the iteration inside the function may be faster on a contiguous copy.

Comment: In modern Fortran there are _four_ main ways of passing arrays: assumed shape, explicit shape, deferred shape; assumed size (yes, even in modern Fortran). But they each have different meanings.

Comment: Note that `pause` is not legal Fortran. It was deleted, not just marked obsolete, already in Fortran 90 or 95. It was never really well defined for general situations. If your program is supposed to wait for Enter, just use `print *,`. Also `real(8)` is not portable, magic numbers like `8` are ugly and do not belong to these contexts.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I updated my code example replacing with real(8) with smth portable, thanks. I tried to replace pause with print *, but it gives me an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With assumed shape you can achieve passing non-contiguous arrays or their  without temporary copies. The receiving subroutine knows where the individual parts are in memory and can jump between them thanks to the dope vector in the array descriptor. That means that you avoid a temporary copy, but the iteration through the array is more complicated and may be slower.

If an assumed shape array has the `contiguous` attribute, the compiler can generate simpler and faster code, but if the actual argument is not contiguous, a temporary copy must be made.

For explicit-size arrays, the dummy argument is always contiguous. However, a temporary copy will be necessary if the actual argument is not contiguous.

---

With assumed shape arrays you get the benefit of better argument checking by the compiler during the compilation, because the explicit interface is always available. Some checking will be possible even for explicit-size arrays if the explicit interface is available and sometimes even when it is not, but the possibilities are more limited.

One reason for that is that thanks or due to the storage association rules  it is possible to pass an array with a different rank and with a total size (number of elements) larger (or equal) to the size  declared in the shape of the dummy argument of the explicit size array.

For an assumed shape the shape is passed automatically with the array descriptor. Therefore passing a smaller or larger than a declared size  is a concept that does not exist for them, they simply work differently.

In many ways these types of array dummy arguments are just way too different and differ in what you can do with them. It is not just one or the other because of speed. They strongly differ in the way they are used. For explicit size arrays you have to provide the size somehow.

This differences can be illustrated by the examples offered by francescalus:

```
call sub_trace_es(2, real([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], dp), trace)
```

this asks for a trace of a 2x2 array. The argument being passed is a 1D array containing 9 elements. However, only the first four will be considered. The matrix the subroutine will look at is

```
1 3
2 4
```

(column-major order) and the trace will be 5.

For

```
call subtrace( reshape(real([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], dp), [3,3]), trace)
```

the same 9-element numeric sequence is reshaped into a 3x3 array. Hence the matrix the subroutine will look at is

```
1   4   7
2   5   8
3   6   9
```

and the trace will be 15.

---

I personally use assumed shape with the explicit `contiguous` attribute in several places of my production code for supercomputers where large arrays are passed around. However, be careful to enable warnings about temporary copies, it is easy to forget this in one location and than you spoil everything by unnecessary temporaries.

In most parts of my code, that are not so performance-critical, I just use assumed shape without further attributes.

Comment: Perhaps essential points of an answer would be include rank and number of elements in actual and dummy arguments?

Comment: These are quite extensively discussed in your linked answer so I mentioned these implicitly, but I can certainly touch  it more, I was still in the process of expanding the answer.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't go overboard (with the context of the linked question), but if I were answering I'd stress that `call sub_trace_es(2, [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.], trace)` is so very different from `call subtrace(reshape([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6. 7.,8.,9.],[3,3]),trace)` well beyond those other aspects.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава thanks for your detailed answer! However the first example calling sub_trace_es does not compile (I added it to my code). Error message: the type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument. This is indeed what I expected: the subroutine sub_trace_es expects a matrix and if you pass a one-dimensional array the compiler detects the mismatch

Comment: @Alessandro Do not confuse a type a kind and a rank. A type mismatch means in the error message means actually a mismatch in a basic type or in a kind. Because your subroutine expects `real(dp)`, you must provide `real(dp)` and not just the default real. Please always take such examples as possibly simplified ones in these kind of examples.

Comment: The dp real can be achieved by using `1._dp` or by using the `real(x, dp)` conversion function. In your original `real(8)` it would be the same, just with 8 instead of dp.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава got it, thanks! Explicit-shape dummy arrays can be very dangerous, then. I tried first with `call sub_trace(real([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],dp), trace4)` and the compiler correctly detected the shape mismatch. However if I try `call sub_trace_es(2, real([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],dp), trace3)` the code compiles and runs but it does not make sense b/c the dummy argument in the subroutine is a matrix and instead I am passing a vector!

Comment: @Alessandro Many use cases of this make very good sense. You can search this site and the web for "sequence association". Matrices and vectors are linear algebra objects defined for linear operators in some bases on linear vector spaces. Fortran knows arrays (with the exception of matmul()). Matrices and vectors can be somehow stored in arrays of various ranks.