# Passing size of array as argument to a subroutine in fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, size, subroutine

I was wondering about the overhead of querying size of array in fortran. Old fortran (<f95) way was to pass the size of array to the arguments of subroutine:

```
subroutine asub(nelem,ar)
integer,intent(in)::nelem
real*8,intent(in)::ar(:)

! do stuff with nelem such as allocate other arrays

end subroutine asub
```

Since the size function of f95, it can be done this way:

```
subroutine asub(ar)
real*8,intent(in)::ar(:)

! do stuff with size(ar) such as allocate other arrays

end subroutine asub
```

Is method 2 bad performance-wise if asub is called million times ?

I am asking because I am working on a relatively big code where some array sizes are global variables (not even passed as subroutine arguments), which is really bad in my opinion. Method 1 would require a lot of work in order to propagate the array sizes to the whole code while method 2 is clearly faster to achieve in my case.

Thanks !

---

Comment: `size` existed before Fortran 95 and your first example was not valid before Fortran 90. Passing `nelem` as an argument changes the meaning of your code (especially if it's used as the size of the dummy array) so it's impossible/meaningless to compare them in the abstract. Of course, you can profile your own specific cases but the base assumption will be that any additional cost of using `size(ar)` will be trivial compared with what's done with the value.

Comment: If you mean to consider `ar(nelem)` and `ar(:)` instead, then [this other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75051887/3157076) is unarguably relevant.

Comment: *Method 1 would require a lot of work in order to propagate the array sizes to the whole code while method 2 is clearly faster to achieve in my case.* This is why I use assumed shape arrays for my production code. I just use the `contiguous` attribute to pass the large ones. Using `allocatable` could be an interesting alternative in certain cases, but usually it does not make sense.

Comment: thank you francescalus and Vladimir. Method 1 is odd but it is done this way in the current code, sometimes nelem is not even present in the argument of the function/subroutine but imported from an other module (this is what I call a global variable). I will then consider refactoring using method 2 which is likely a more modern approach. As you said, I did some simple timing tests and indeed querying size of array versus reading nelem from memory gives no difference, at least it is hidden by any additional operation I do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nelem` is a number that you need to read from memory, `size(ar)` is also a number that you need to read from memory. And you need to inquire the value just once. And then probably do a lot of computation over `nelem` elements. The overhead inquiring the size of the value will be completely negligible.

OK, `size(ar)` is a function call, but the compiler can just insert reading the right value from the array descriptor). And even if it remains a function call, still it will be called just once.

Differences, if any, will be elsewhere, mainly as described in the Q/A linked linked by francescalus [Passing arrays to subroutines in Fortran: Assumed shape vs explicit shape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75051887/3157076). Depending on what the compiler can assume about the array being contiguous in memory it will be able to optimize it better or worse (e.g. SIMD vectorization).

As always, where performance matters, you should test and measure. Remember to enable all relevant compiler optimizations.