how to fix that double array is empty after passing to external function in Fortran
I have been experiencing this problem that if I pass a double array in a function that is written in a different file, it is empty. Maybe there is a very simple solution, but I don't know it.
program_test.f90:
program test
   use iso_fortran_env
   implicit none
   real(real64), allocatable :: u(:, :)
   real(real64) :: res
   real(real64), external :: test_function

   allocate(u(17, 17))
   if (.not. allocated(u)) then
      print *, "Memory allocation failed for u or f."
      stop
   end if
   print *, "Before entering test_function"
   print *, "Size of u: ", size(u, 1), size(u, 2)
   print *, "Contents of u (first few values): ", u(1:2, 1:2)
   u = 0.

   res = test_function(u)

end program test

function_test.f90:
function test_function(u) result(res)
   use iso_fortran_env
   implicit none
   real(real64),intent(inout):: u(:,:)  ! arguments
   real(real64) res

   print *, "Entering test_function"
   print *, "Size of u: ", size(u, 1), size(u, 2)
   print *, "Contents of u (first few values): ", u(1:5, 1:5)

   res = 0.

end function test_function

command to compile and run it:
gfortran program_test.f90 function_test.f90 -o program_test.out -Wall && ./program_test.out
output:
Before entering test_function
 Size of u:           17          17
 Contents of u (first few values):    0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000     
 Entering test_function
 Size of u:            1           1
 Contents of u (first few values): 

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Ofcourse I first set u = 0. before printing the  size and first values in test_program.f90, that was a mistake in the post. Output is still the same.

Calling a function (or subroutine) that has an assumed-shape dummy requires (what Fortran calls) an explicit interface (and NOT merely an external declaration) at the call site: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766530/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913804/ and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486822/ . Note if you concatenate these program-units in one sourcefile and compile that gfortran does diagnose the error (though you need to add a module, subprogram nesting, or interface block to fix it).
